# Javafx Webview Problem Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:

Tags: java, javafx, webview, java-11

I am very new to java fx , I am just trying to add WebView component. So everytime adding `WebView` Intellij returns a problem.

Here is output:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
```

Here is my sample.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.WebView?>


<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <WebView fx:id="myweb" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

Here is my controller:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private WebView myweb;

}
```

If I am adding another stuff, everything works well, but after adding `WebView` it returns error.

Also I heard that `WebView` is not being supported in jdk 11. Is that true?

Comment: 1. If you are using Java 11, did you add the module javafx.web to your module path? 2. WebView is still supported even in the latest version of JavaFX which is 13.

Comment: You're hiding the most important part of the stacktrace from us. Usually the bottommost part is the most interesting, but it doesn't hurt to post all of it, does it?

Answer (score 3):

Just **add** the word `javafx.web` to your **VM Options** after your modules.

You can use the following line of code in your VM Options and add any other modules you're using.

`--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.web`